# Spray route testing with Akka TestProbe

Tags: scala, spray, specs2, spray-test, akka-testkit

In my Spray route, I delegate to an actor to process the request. The `RequestContext` is sent in the message to that actor.

```
path("mypath") {
  parameters("thing".as[String]) { thing => ctx =>
    myActor ! ProcessThingAndResondToContext(thing, ctx)
  }
}
```

In my test, I substitute a `TestProbe` for the actor, because the actor's processing is expensive.

```
class MySpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with ScalaCheck with MyService {
  val testProbe = TestProbe()
  override val myActor = testProbe.ref

  def is = s2"""
    it should $doTheRightThing
  """

  def doTheRightThing = {
    Get(s"/mypath?thing=fruit") ~> route ~> check {
      testProbe.expectMsgClass(classOf[ProcessThingAndResondToContext])
      status mustEqual StatusCodes.Success
    }
  }
```

This spec fails because there's no `status`. The TestProbe does nothing and so the `ctx` was never responded to.

```
Request was neither completed nor rejected within 1 second
```

The line `status mustEqual StatusCodes.Success` is not crucial to my test, but I can't remove it because then the spec doesn't compile - the method no longer typechecks as a `MatchResult`.

How can I test the route delegated to the actor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve the question, but resolved my problem by using a `TestActorRef` instead of a `TestProbe`. Then I could specify a simplified behaviour and still respond to `ctx`.